# htaccess editing to avoid duplicating

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in my website  i have this .htaccess code

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^einfogarden.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.einfogarden.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=302,L,NE]

# convert %20 to -
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [N,NE]
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" $1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ single.php?title=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

where i convert the 20% with -
but the problem is the backslash "/" in the end is repeated according to the "-" number, how can i get just one backslash

Comment: Provide some examples. What is the URL adding multiple slashes?

Comment: http://www.einfogarden.com/%D9%81%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF-%D8%B9%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83////

Comment: http://www.einfogarden.com/%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%B7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82%D8%A9-%D8%B3%D9%87%D9%84%D8%A9////

Comment: Those are URLs after adding multiple slashes. I need to know what were original URLs before this effect?

Comment: http://www.einfogarden.com/single.php?title=%D9%81%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF%20%D8%B9%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83

Comment: www.einfogarden.com/single.php?title=%D9%81%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF%20%D8%B9%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%88%D9%86%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^einfogarden.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.einfogarden.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=302,L,NE]

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

# convert %20 to -
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [L,NE]
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" $1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ single.php?title=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

i.e rearrange and remove `N` flag.